# Two equations with sub equations

Tags: equations

I would like to produce the following format.

A=A   B=B

C=C   D=D   E=E

I tried using align. However, I failed to get the required output. Please correct me.

```
\begin{align*}  A&=A & B&B \\     C&=C  & D&=D  &E&E    \end{align*}
```

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: I would say that you need the same number of `&` on each lines to align them together. Do you have the `amsmath` loaded in your preamble?

Comment: `\begin {align*}  A&=A & B&=B \\     C&=C  & D&=D  & E&=E    \end{align*}`

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks for the correction. This is of great help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for centred, gathered equations, then use `gather*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
Some text before
\begin{gather*}
  A=A \qquad B=B \\
  C=C \qquad D=D \qquad E=E
\end{gather*}
and some text after.
\end{document}
```

For more horizontally-aligned content, `align*` works fine, but you'll have a dangling equation (in the second row):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
Some text before
\begin{align*}
  A &= A & B &= B \\
  C &= C & D &= D & E &= E
\end{align*}
and some text after.
\end{document}
```

There are options as well, depending on whether you want them numbered or aligned.

Comment: Hi Werner, Thanks for giving me the more generic one. It has educated me.